# Linker error while compiling code in Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I am trying to compile my C++ code in Windows cmd.
I have implemented UnitTest++ in the project. When I run:

```
g++ main.cpp -IC:\Test\TreeObjModel\include -IC:\Test\unittest-cpp-master\UnitTest++
```

it gives the following error:

> undefined reference to `UnitTest::RunAllTests()' collect2.exe: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone help me to resolve this? Is any more info needed?

Comment: Is UnitTest some external lib?

Comment: Yes. UnitTest++ is a library for developing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing to compile some other `cpp` file (`UnitTest.cpp`?); or maybe you must link to some UnitTest library, where the code for `UnitTest::RunAllTests()` resides.

The command line option for linking a library with GCC is `-l library_name`.